# How to filter datetime field in datatable disregarding the time value of it in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, datatable, datetimepicker

I tried this code:

```
(datagridview1.DataSource as DataTable).Select("date_time=" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtpDate.Text.ToString()));
```

but I thinks it still include the time and gets me error "Syntax error: Missing operand after '12' operator."

What I really want to happen is that filter the datetime field of datable disregarding the time of it, just the date.

Here is what my datagridview looks like:

```
1   1   1/24/2013 12:34 AM  
1   2   1/24/2013 12:34 AM  
2   3   1/24/2013 12:53 AM  
3       1/25/2013 12:30 AM  
4       1/25/2013 12:53 AM  
5   4   1/25/2013 2:10 AM   
6   5   1/25/2013 2:26 AM   
7   6   1/25/2013 2:39 AM   
8   7   1/25/2013 2:40 AM
```

Updated code:

```
datagridview1.DataSource = (datagridview1.DataSource as DataTable).AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("date_time").HasValue 
                    && r.Field<DateTime?>("date_time").Value.Date == dt.Date).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use strings when you want to compare dates. You can use `Linq-To-DataTable` and the strongly typed `DataRow` extension method `Field`. Then use the `Date` property of `DateTime`.

```
DateTime  dt = DateTime.Parse(dtpDate.Text);
DataTable filteredRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("date_time").Date == dt.Date)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

**Edit** (according to your comment)

> "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.

Then you have `nulls` in this field. Since the [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) method supports [nullable-types](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime) you can use it directly.

```
DataTable filteredRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("date_time").HasValue 
            &&  r.Field<DateTime?>("date_time").Value.Date == dt.Date)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

**Edit** So you get an exception when the table is empty. Yes, `CopyToDataTable` throws an `InvalidOperationException` when  the source table is empty.

Note that perhaps you don't need to copy the result into a new `DataTable` at all. You could bind the query itself to the datasource property of the datagridview, so try to simply omit the `CopyToDataTable`.

```
var filteredRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("date_time").HasValue 
            &&  r.Field<DateTime?>("date_time").Value.Date == dt.Date);

datagridview1.DataSource = filteredRows;
```

Otherwise you could also check if the query returns anything:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
if(filteredRows.Any())
{
    table = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: got confused, in my (datagridview1.datasource as datatable) how can i use that line of code in your solution?

Comment: @MekeniKine: `var table = datagridview1.DataSource as DataTable;`.

Comment: gets me error "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type."

Comment: @MekeniKine: Then you have `nulls` in this field. Since the `Field` method supports nullable-types you can use it directly. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @TimSchemelter, I got problem encountered after I click the button filter the output is okay but when I click it again it prompts error the source does not contains no DataRows"

Comment: @MekeniKine: _"does not contains no"_ means it contains rows or was that a typo? What is throwing this error? Show the stack trace.

Comment: "The source contains no DataRows." sorry for the type, i post my new code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23767/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-mekenikine)

Answer (score 1):

```
            DataView dv = new DataView(Datatable1);
            dv.RowFilter = "StartDate >= #" + DtpDateRangeFrom.Value + "# AND StartDate <= #" + DtpDateRangeTo.Value + "#";
```